# Access length of current Spotify music being played on Mac from python

Tags: python, macos, spotify

I'm trying to access the length of a track currently being played on Spotify on a Mac from python.
The idea is to have a script that automatically turns down the volume if a track is less than 60s and turns it back up if the track is longer than 60s (mute ads).

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this link. It's however not solving my problem as I need to access data from what is currently being played by the Desktop app.

Comment: AFAIK, the desktop app has no such open API

Comment: @OneCricketeer, what about macOS? Is there a way to access the length of a track from the operating system?

Comment: Maybe? For example, on the Touchbar models, you can seek the track, but hard to say how to tap into that information